# Рандом из определенных чисел с зависимостью

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите , возможно ли реализовать данную мысль (ротация баннеров) на php :

1. имеем список id-баннеров, которые показываются в одном блоке (1,5,8,12)
2. у каждого баннера своя ставка за клик
3. частота показов зависит от ставки

В какую сторону копать ? как установить частоту показов , объясните логику ?

Возможно, моя идея не совершенна и можно сделать по-другому. Хотелось бы увидеть рекомендации. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

- суммируете ставки кликов подходящих баннеров
- выбираете любую точку от 0 до этой суммы. `random_int` для более равномерного распределения, но можно и `mt_rand`, не криптография всё-таки
- находите, какому баннеру принадлежала выбранная точка

Получается как-то так:

```
function chooseBanner(array $banners) {
    $sum = array_sum($banners);
    if (! $sum) {
        return null;
    }
    $point = random_int(0, $sum);
    foreach ($banners as $id => $bid) {
        $sum -= $bid;
        if ($point >= $sum) {
            return $id;
        }
    }
    throw new \LogicException('normal unreachable code');
}
```

И небольшой тест распределения 50 тысяч показов:

```
$banners = [
    // id баннера -> ставка
    5 => 33,
    16 => 7,
    8 => 10,
];
// testcase
$visibles = array_fill_keys(array_keys($banners), 0);
for ($i = 0; $i<50000; $i++) {
    $visibles[ chooseBanner($banners) ]++;
}
var_dump($visibles);
```

Результат теста:

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  int(33275)
  [16]=>
  int(6787)
  [8]=>
  int(9938)
}
```

Вполне соответствует распределению ставок.

Comment: Наверно, все-таки не нормального, а равномерного распределения? Это как бы довольно разные вещи. :)

Comment: Проклятье, не подумал о математическом смысле "нормальное" распределение. Ещё не оклемался после трёхднейвной конференции. Да, имелось в виду что random_int даст разброс значений поближе к желаемому равномерному распределению.